# Access to the database of a prestahsop turnkey hosting company

Tags: database, prestashop, hosting, web-hosting

i am developing a module for prestashop, this module create a table in the database during its installation.

But I read a long time ago, that some hosters especially turnkey, can block access to the database (make a CREATE TABLE) to the modules.

I do not find info on the net, someone would have info.

Comment: If hosting allows to install Prestashop it makes no sense that it blocks table creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hosting allows to install Prestashop it makes no sense that it blocks table creation.
You can try a module test generated by PS creator (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) and watch if table is properly created.

I am PS developer and work with several hostings and never had problems.

Modules installation is a common task, it is strange to have not create table permission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my module is working, my question is have you ever had problems with hosts that offer pre-installed prestahsop?

Comment: I have had any problem like that. Think about usual payment methods need module installation: credit card, paypal, amazon pay, sofort, sequra and more. Prestashop has improved pretty much, but you still need modules for many stuffs. A hosting which offers PS but does not allow modules installation is really crazy, I never have seen that before.